# How to display percentage along with Count value in Pie chart Using Higcharts Plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, highcharts

I have tried following way to draw pie chart using Highchart plugin with PHP
[image]

In above Pie Chart, I want to display A Percentage along with Count 2 in piechart like A: 67.0 % (2) and B: 33.0 % (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highcharts pie chart has an option for setting your own formatter for the data labels. See https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter

In there you have access to:

```
this.percentage     Stacked series and pies only. The point's percentage of the total.
this.point      The point object. The point name, if defined, is available through this.point.name.
this.series:    The series object. The series name is available through this. series.name.
this.total     Stacked series only. The total value at this point's x value.
this.x:   The x value.
this.y:   The y value.
```